# WSO2 Api Manager behind Apache

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am setting a UniqueId for every request in Apache which is proxying requests back to WSO2 Api Manager. How do I have the UniqueId logged with every request which reaches the API Manager ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an [Axis2 handler](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/08/writing-simple-axis2-handler.html) to log the MessageID and keep the handler in the Inlfow.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this. Just curious to know if Tomcat is even affected by API calls to the API Manager ?

Comment: Not clear..If,  you set a uniqueID for your message( eg as a soap header) You should be able to get that from handler.

Comment: The unique id is not part of the soap header. It is part of the HTTP Header. I managed to ad a Handler but I am getting "ERROR - ServerHandler Unexpected HTTP protocol error : Transfer-encoding header already presen" when I try to log the header information.

Comment: Also, For some reason I am not able to obtain the header I am setting at the Apache end. Does the API Manager retain any incoming headers when behind a proxy ?